# Qt and sqlite error 26

Tags: sqlite, qt

I try to open an Sqlite database with Qt to execute the following query:

```
select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table';
```

And the database gets opened successfully, but when I execute the query, I get error 26: `file is encrypted or is not a database`. When I open the same database with the `sqlite` command line, however it works fine. Qt version is 4.8.1, the sqlite file starts with `** This file contains an SQLite 2.1 database **` operating system is Linux, sqlite version installed is 2.8.17.

Any idea what is wrong with this?

Thanks,
f.

`Edit:` Opening it like:

```
QSqlDatabase dbo = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "connName");
dbo.setDatabaseName("/home/myself/test.sqlite");
dbo.open();
if(!dbo.isOpen())
{
    qDebug() << dbo.lastError();
    return;
}
QSqlQuery query(dbo);
bool ok = query.exec("select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table';");
if(!ok)
{ 
  //get error code, etc...
}
```

and it is Not OK :(

`Edit2:` I have tried with a different sqlite file, one which starts with: `SQLite format 3` and it works nicely. Seems out of the box Qt support for Sqlite 2 is not working as expected.

Comment: Show us how you open and query it.

Comment: Execute `SELECT sqlite_version();` with Qt.

Comment: Try renaming `test.sqlite` to `test.db`.

Comment: @CL. the version printed out is 3.7.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite 3.x (as included in Qt) cannot open SQLite 2 files.

SQLite 2 has been obsolete for many years.
You should upgrade your databse:

```sh
sqlite2 old-db.sqlite .dump > backupfile
sqlite3 new-db.sqlite < backupfile
```

Comment: Yes, this is a very good point ... Thanks! BTW, if you specify QSQLITE2 for the database engine it can work with sqlite2 files too.